# Analogies and relations between evenness and squareness in arbitrary rings

Tags: ring-theory, square-numbers

Being even and being a square in arbitrary rings $R$ are analogous by definition:

> $p \in R$ is **even** if there is an $a \in R$ with $p = a + a =: 2a$.
>
> $p \in R$ is a **square** if there is an $b \in R$ with $p = b \cdot b =: b^2$.

I wonder if there other **analogies** between the two concepts (than this one by definition).

And which other **relations** are there between them next to:

> **(1)** When $p$ is a square then $b$ is even iff $p$ is even.

*[Note that no analogy arises from* "When $p$ is even then $a$ is a square iff $p$ is a square" *because the latter is false.]*

Furthermore:

> How do you prove that when $p$ is an even square, i.e. $p= a + a = b\cdot b$, then $b$ is even, i.e. $b = c + c$?

(The other direction is easy.)

Comment: When you say "arbitrary ring", is it entirely arbitrary? No assumptions about unit or commutativity?

Comment: The definitions above don't make such assumptions: there's no unit around, and commutativity in $a+a$ and $b\cdot b$ is not an issue.

Comment: As always: The OP loves to learn the reasons for downvoting.

Comment: If I'm not overlooking something, in the ring $((\Bbb Z/4)[x])/\langle x^2-2\rangle$, with your definitions, $x^2$ is even but $x$ is not.

Comment: Are there more simple counter-examples for **(1)**? (I find your counter-example quite hard to digest.) Can you tell a criterion on $R$ such that **(1)** holds? Might $\operatorname{char}(R) = 0$ suffice?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2)$ works : $X^2 = 0$ is even, but $X$ definitely isn't

Comment: $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]$ also works, and is a Euclidean domain of characteristic $0$. -- The statement is trivially true for skew fields, but these examples suggest that beyond that, it's not trivial to characterise rings which satisfy it.